# Definition of Partition in Analysis vs Topology

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading through two books side by side, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin* (Baby Rudin) and *Topology : A First Course by Munkres* and I've picked up a difference in the definition of partition in both books.

Munkres defines a *partition* in the following way (Set-Theoretic Definition) :

> A *partition* of a set $A$ is a collection of disjoint non-empty subsets of $A$ whose union is all of $A$. Symbolically $$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_i = A \ \ \text{where} \ A_i \subset A \ \ \text{and} \ \ A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset \ \ \text{for} \ \  i\neq j$$

Rudin defines a *partition* in the following way

> Let $[a,b]$ be a given interval. By a *partition*, $P$ of $[a,b]$ we mean a finite set of points $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ where $a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq ... \leq x_n = b$

To me it seems to be that *Munkres* definition is the general one, and that Rudin's definition *should be* a special case of *Munkres* definition when the set $A$, just so happens to be an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

But I can't seem to reconcile Rudin's definition with Munkres' one. Because if we let $A = [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is *uncountably infinite*. But if we define a partition in Rudin's way, then a partition, $P$ of $A$ has only finitely many elements, and in fact it's not at all clear whether the elements of $P$ are subsets of $A$ or elements of $A$.

---

For example take $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. By *Munkres* definition a partition of $[0,1]$ could be $P = \left\{ \ \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right) \ , \left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\},  \ \left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right] \ \right\}$.

But by *Rudin's* definition a partition of $[0,1]$ could be $P= \{ 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1 \}$, and we can't even talk about the union equalling $[0,1]$, as for that the elements of $P$ would themselves have to be subsets of $[0,1]$ which they are not. e.g. $\{0\} \subset [0,1]$, but $0 \not\subset [0,1]$. For *Rudin's* definition to even make sense in terms of *Munkres* definition, $P$ would have to be something like the following $P = \left\{ \{0\}, \{\frac{1}{2}\}, \{1\} \right\}$, and in that case it *still* doesn't account for the fact that $\bigcup_{i} P_i \neq A$ where $P_i \in P$

So this leads me to believe that the definition of *partition* in terms of Analysis and Topology differ. If they are indeed the same definition, then how can they be shown to be the same?

Comment: $[x_0,x_1)\cup\cdots\cup[x_{n-1},x_n]$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ in both definitions

Comment: @user160738, But $\{0, 1\}$ is a valid partition of $[0,1]$ by Rudin's definition, but an invalid one by Munkres' definition

Comment: While Rudin says that set of points define a partition, by saying that what he really means is that we have a set theoretic partition defined by those points, as defined in my previous comment. So it really is the same definition

Comment: The idea is the same, we want to split a set into disjoint pieces. However, when we're dealing with Riemann integration, the only kind of interesting partition is partition into finite ordered sets. In that case, specifying the end points uniquely determines the ''partition'' in the usual sense.

Comment: @user160738 An answer to a similar question says that they are different definitions : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/177056/266135

Comment: Yes they are different, only the idea about splitting a set is the same.

Comment: The accepted answer in your link discusses that specifying endpoints uniquely specifes a partition of the interval, but in general case sets are not interval so such definition cannot work in general case. But for intervals they do coincide - at least that's what I can tell from that answer

Comment: When Rudin is talking about partition, he is not talking about partition in the sense of Munkres. Although he is using the same phrase but the important thing to remember is that they represent different concepts.